# How to return value from a child process in a function?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, botframework, child-process

I spawn a python child process in javascript (for coding a Bot with Microsoft Botframework) like this:

```
async function searchForRelevantDoc (context) {
    var msg = context.activity.text;
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        py    = spawn('python', ['../path/to/file.py', msg]),
        output = '';
    py.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';
    py.stdout.on('data',
    (data) => {
        output += data.toString();
        console.log('output was generated: ' + output);
    });
    // Handle error output
    py.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    // As said before, convert the Uint8Array to a readable string.
        console.log('error:' + data);
    });
    py.stdout.on('end', async function(code){
        console.log('output: ' + output);
        console.log(`Exit code is: ${code}`);
        // "return" is probably wrong, what should be done instead?
        return output;
        }
    });
}
```

I want `output` to be returned as the value of the function `searchForRelevanceDoc()`. How can this be done? I am not able to use 
`await context.sendActivity(output)`
instead of the return statement. Error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
```

Function `searchForRelevanceDoc` is called like so:

```
//in bot.js
const pysearch = require('../bboti/python-search');

class MyBot {

    // constructor...

    async onTurn(context) {
        // ...
        var search_engine_answer = pysearch.searchForRelevantDoc(context);
        context.sendActivity(search_engine_answer)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: show stacktrace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to return/resolve `output` from `searchForRelevantDoc`, using `async/await` is to use `events.once` which was added in Node 11.13.0, and wait for `close` event of `py`

```
const { once } = require('events'); // Added in Node 11.13.0

async function searchForRelevantDoc (context) {
    var msg = context.activity.text;
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        py    = spawn('python', ['../path/to/file.py', msg]),
        output = '';

    py.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';

    py.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        output += data.toString();
        console.log('output was generated: ' + output);
    });
    // Handle error output
    py.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    // As said before, convert the Uint8Array to a readable string.
        console.log('error:' + data);
    });
    py.stdout.on('end', async function(code){
        console.log('output: ' + output);
        console.log(`Exit code is: ${code}`);
    });

    await once(py, 'close')

    return output;
}
```

If you're using an older version of Node, you can wrap it in a `new Promise`

```js
async function searchForRelevantDoc (context) {
    // ...

    // You can also check for `code` and reject if a non zero code is returned
    await new Promise(resolve => py.on('close', resolve));

    return output;
}
```

---

Then when calling `searchForRelevantDoc` you need to use `await` or `.then`

```js
class MyBot {

    // constructor...

    async onTurn(context) {
        // ...
        var search_engine_answer = await pysearch.searchForRelevantDoc(context);
        context.sendActivity(search_engine_answer)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The first option didn't work because `once` is not defined. So I tried the second option and I still got the same error. Exit code on console is `undefined`. Thank you for your help so far, just didn't work sadly.

Comment: Once is undefined because you may be using a lower version than the one I explicitly mentioned.

Comment: And I can guarantee that that's how you return correctly. You may be doing something you're not showing to us. Show how you're calling that function.

Comment: Alright, I added the essentials of my bot.js, where the function is called.

Comment: Check updated answer, you're missing `await`. Always post the whole code.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Used the option for the older Node version plus await when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

@Marcos Casagrande's answer is more beautiful, I just wanted to add the promise solution as well.

You can just return a `new Promise` and wrap the `stdout.on` inside the promise.

```
async function searchForRelevantDoc (context) {
...
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        py.stdout.on('end', async function(code){
            console.log('output: ' + output);
            console.log(`Exit code is: ${code}`);
            // "return" is probably wrong, what should be done instead?
            res(output);
        })
    });
}
```

Promises `hot-load` so whenever you declare a promise the function will start to run. So basically the event will be attached.

Answer (score 0):

Make your function
`return new Promise((resovle, reject) => ...)`
and resolve needed value